# How to grab Sycnfusion ScheduleView's VisibleDate

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

At the moment, I query my appointments within VisibleDatesChangedEvent event. I would like to query on demand but I'm wondering how can I access Visible Dates.

Agenda.xaml

```
<schedule:SfSchedule> 
     ....
     VisibleDatesChangedEvent="schedule_VisibleDatesChangedEvent"
     ....
</schedule:SfSchedule>

private async void schedule_VisibleDatesChangedEvent(object sender, VisibleDatesChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var sfScheduleEventArgs = (VisibleDatesChangedEventArgs)e;

   var sfSchedule = sfScheduleEventArgs.Schedule;

   //Default Values to get data for two months
   var firstDay = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
   var lastDay = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
   if (sfScheduleEventArgs.visibleDates.Any())
   {
       firstDay = sfScheduleEventArgs.visibleDates.First();
       lastDay = sfScheduleEventArgs.visibleDates.Last();
   }
   var vm = (AgendaViewModel)this.BindingContext;
   var data = await vm.GetAgendasListAsync(firstDay, lastDay);
   vm.Meetings = new ObservableCollection<FullCalendarEventDto>(data.Items);
```

}

Now I want to create a simple button to GetAgendasList but my problem is I'm having trouble accessing visibleDates

Comment: there is no VisibleDates property, so your best bet is probably to store the VisibleDates value in a class variable whenever the event fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have analyzed your query “To get the visible dates in run time in schedule” as of now schedule doesn’t have direct property to get the visible dates, you can get the visible dates from the VisibleDatesChangedEventArgs of VisibleDateChangedEvent in schedule and the event occurs whenever the schedule view changed/navigated.

You can achieve your requirement by defining a local parameter in your class file and you can store the visible dates to the local variables from the VisibleDatesChagned event and you can access the date. We have prepared a simple sample for the same.

Sample link: [Schedule](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ScheduleSample_(2)532350518)

Regards,
Subburaj Pandian
*Syncfusion Support Team*